# Recursive headache

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

**The task**:

Given a 2D array `m` containing **whole non negative numbers**, we will define a **"path"** as a collection of neighboring cells(diagonal steps **do not count as neighbor**) starting at `row == 0 && col == 0` and ending with `row == m.length - 1 && col == m[0].length - 1`.

The **cost** of a "path" is the sum of the values in each cell of the "path".

**Example:**

Two of the possible paths in an array:
[image: possible paths in an array]

The cost of path 1(dashed line): 8 + 4 + 2 + 8 + 9 + 9 + 7 + 5 = 52;

The cost of path 2(full line): 8 + 6 + 3 + 8 + 9 + 4 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 7 + 6 + 5 = 60

**TO DO:**

Write a `static` recursive method that accepts a 2D array `m` filled with **whole non negative values** and prints the sum of all the possible path costs(you may assume that `m` is not `null` nor empty).

Method signature is(overloading is allowed):

`public static void printPathWeights(int [][] m)`

**My code:**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int arr[][] = { { 1, 1, 1 },
                        { 1, 1, 1 },
                        { 1, 1, 1 }
        };

        printPathWeights(arr);

    }

    public static void printPathWeights(int[][] m) {
        System.out.println(printPathWeights(m, 0, 0, new int[m.length][m[0].length], 0));
    }


    /*
     * @param map marks the visited cells
     */
    private static int printPathWeights(int[][] m, int row, int col, int[][] map, int carrier) {

        if (row < 0 || col < 0 || row >= m.length || col >= m[0].length || map[row][col] == 1)
            return 0;

        if (row == m.length - 1 && col == m[0].length - 1)
            return m[row][col] + carrier;

        map[row][col] = 1;
        return printPathWeights(m, row + 1, col, map, carrier + m[row][col]) +
                printPathWeights(m, row - 1, col, map, carrier + m[row][col]) +
                printPathWeights(m, row, col + 1, map, carrier + m[row][col]) +
                printPathWeights(m, row, col - 1, map, carrier + m[row][col]);

    }

}
```

The printed value of the above code is: 14

Which is less than expected!

When ran with:

```
    int arr[][] = { { 1, 1 },
                    { 1, 1 }
    };
```

The result is 6 as expected.

**What is wrong in my code?**

PS: please do not present me with code that solves the assignment but explain what is wrong with my code.

Comment: map[row][col] = 1; consider that logic again

Comment: I assume `map` is supposed to be the *visited* map? If so, consider the following exploration sequence: Path 1: *down*, Path 2: *left*, *down*, *right*. Exploration halts here, since you have already visited this node in Path 1.

Comment: @HunterLarco what is wrong with marking the current `row` `col` as 1?

Comment: @DimaMaligin assume two distinct paths visit the same cell. Marking the cell with 1 means it was visited. So the first path reaches the cell, it is marked as visited. Second path reaches the cell, but it is already marked as visited -> end of the path, though it would continue with that cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code marks cells visited as soon as an arbitrary path reaches that cell. But this cell is afterwards aswell marked as visited for all other cells and won't be visited again. This means the algorithm only finishes a subset of the paths and some traversals break off somewhere in the middle of the array for bigger arrays. You'll have to mark the cells as visited separately for each path.

Simply reset the map after each access of a new cell:

```
    printPathWeights(...)
        //analyze the current cell
        markCellVisited(currentCell)

        int tmp = visitAllNeighbours()

        resetVisitedState(currentCell)

        return tmp
```

This would be the most efficient and simple way. Since the cellstate is reset after accessing the cell, it will never remain marked from the previous path.

Comment: so basically in every call i should create a new "cloned" map and mark the cell on the clone?

Comment: It seems like i made the mistake of assuming that the `map` passed on is a totally different array. but I was wrong cause every recursive call made changes to the original map. Thank you!

Comment: While you answer is correct( I thank you for it ;) ), I must add that incomplete paths return 0 including the sub paths so any incomplete path count as 0 added to the total. I might be wrong though and if so please expand on the issue.

Comment: @DimaMaligin oh, you're right. I just misinterpreted a part of the code. sry

Answer (score 1):

As Paul said, the change your code needs is to revert the set of visited cells after the recursive calls.  It prints `76`, as expected.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int arr[][] = { { 1, 1, 1 },
                        { 1, 1, 1 },
                        { 1, 1, 1 }
        };

        printPathWeights(arr);

    }

    public static void printPathWeights(int[][] m) {
        System.out.println(printPathWeights(m, 0, 0, new int[m.length][m[0].length], 0));
    }

    /*
     * @param map marks the visited cells
     */
    private static int printPathWeights(int[][] m, int row, int col, int[][] map, int carrier) {

        if (row < 0 || col < 0 || row >= m.length || col >= m[0].length || map[row][col] == 1)
            return 0;

        if (row == m.length - 1 && col == m[0].length - 1)
            return m[row][col] + carrier;

        map[row][col] = 1;
        int result = printPathWeights(m, row + 1, col, map, carrier + m[row][col]) +
                printPathWeights(m, row - 1, col, map, carrier + m[row][col]) +
                printPathWeights(m, row, col + 1, map, carrier + m[row][col]) +
                printPathWeights(m, row, col - 1, map, carrier + m[row][col]);
        map[row][col] = 0;  // Here
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, well you are correct. But you did the one thing I asked not do do, and that is write code that will solve the issue, I do tank you for your effort(I really do) and you get a +1 from me. But please consider that a good answer should take into account that the person asking the question should learn from the answer and not copy it.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it you are calculating the sum of the weights of all the cells at a time in only one recursion. But not considering the fact that the paths may intersect and that any two paths can have cells in common.like the two paths shown in the illustration have cells in common and have to be added twice

Comment: I did consider that. The thing is that I considered that the map will update with the current path in mind and I was wrong.